# PrimeNG DataTable Filtering filterMatchType not default

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to get a data column to filter based on a "contains" match type, but it doesn't seem to work right for me.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a1UWOtOgg9MkEUAwUP2q?p=preview), try filtering by "f70":

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="orderList">
    <p-column field="itemDesc" header="Item"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" filterPlaceholder="Contains" sortable="custom" (sortFunction)="onItemSort($event)">
      <template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <a [href]="'/e/fm/fm2/item/home.cfm?item_id=' + row['itemId']" target="_blank">{{row['itemNo']}} - {{row['itemDesc']}}</a>
      </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this problem because you are using old version of PrimeNG where filtering had a lot of bugs, to be more precise, version `1.1.2`, which can be seen on line 54 of `systemjs.config.js` file in your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a1UWOtOgg9MkEUAwUP2q?p=preview):

```
'primeng': 'npm:primeng@1.1.2/primeng.js'
```

If you use latest version (`2.0.3`), your filter with `filterMatchMode="contains"` will work like a charm. So, just change version in your `system.config.js` file:

```
'primeng': 'npm:primeng@2.0.3/primeng.js'
```

Comment: Actually that was an artifact of forking someone's plnkr.  And of course I can't duplicate the issue on plnkr with the same versions that I have locally.

Comment: @BillF You should always use latest version. I am using these datatable's a lot and I did a lot of testing on exactly the same thing and I haven't noticed any bugs with filtering using `filterMatchMode="contains"`. Maybe you oversaw something in your code?

Comment: I updated my local version to 2.0.3 from 2.0.2, and still have the same issue.  Using no filterMatchMode (defaults to startsWith) works fine, but if I add filterMatchMode="contains" it doesn't work....in fact it still acts like it is using "startsWith"

Comment: @BillF Maybe old version is still stored in cache, do hard reload. (if you're using Chrome, open console, then right click refresh icon left of the address bar and select "Empty cache and hard reload".

Comment: I was using firefox, but I closed all that down, opened it up in chrome and still the same behavior....startsWith instead of contains

Comment: @BillF Try Chrome and do what I told you, it may still stay in cache even after reopening browser.

Comment: @BillF Then there has to be something else that's messing up with your filtering. Post entire component and its template in your original post.

Comment: edited original post to show actual column definition